# Page is reloaded when wrapping elements with form and making AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If I add a Form around my text elements and make an AJAX call the page is reloaded. If I remove the Form from around my text elements and make an AJAX call the page is not reloaded. For various reasons I need the form (to wrap at least the hidden elements).

Code

```
<div id="mainContent" style="width:500px;position:relative;display:block;margin:0 auto;">
    <p>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="nonce" id="nonce"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="title" id="title"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="content" id="content"/>
        <button onclick="getData('/blog/?json=info')">Get JSON API Info</button>
        <button onclick="getData('/blog/?json=get_recent_posts')">Get Recent Posts</button>
        <button onclick="createPost()">Create Post</button>
        <button onclick="updatePost()">Update Post</button>
        <br><textarea id="responseTextArea" type="text" name="message" style="width: 100%;height:300px"></textarea><br><br>
    </form>
    </p>
</div>

function getData(query) {
    var request = getRequest();
    document.getElementById("responseTextArea").value = "Sending request...";

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("responseTextArea").value = request.responseText;
        }
    }

    request.open("GET", query, true);
    request.send();
}

// utility method for getting asynchronous request
function getRequest() {
    var request;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return request;
}
```

PS I am ***not*** using JQuery. Testing on Firefox 25 Mac.

**UPDATE:**
If I don't wrap any of the buttons the page ***doesn't*** reload! So now I have a workaround but what is going on here? What if I need buttons in my form? Changed code:

```
    <p>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="nonce" id="nonce"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="title" id="title"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="content" id="content"/>
        </form>

        <button onclick="getData('/blog/?json=info')">Get JSON API Info</button>
        <button onclick="getData('/blog/?json=get_recent_posts')">Get Recent Posts</button>
        <button onclick="createPost()">Create Post</button>
        <button onclick="updatePost()">Update Post</button>
        <br><textarea id="responseTextArea" type="text" name="message" style="width: 100%;height:300px"></textarea><br><br>
    </p>
```

Comment: pretty simple...if you don't prevent default handling of button click event in form...form will submit (causing reload), as it should, regardless of you sending ajax. WIthin `onclick` try `return false;` although is better to add unobtrusive event listeners and then you can use `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `type="button"` to each of your button fields, this will prevent them from submitting the form.

Comment: Nice, I'm still new to stack overflow and didn't realize you could do the inline code blocking. `Thanks!`

Answer (score 1):

As Charlie said, that is default form behaviour, if you don't prevent the default behaviour, it Will trigger page refresh. In jQuery you find the submit event and in there you can do something like e.preventDefault();